# Python input validation -- int between 20 and 100, no letters

Tags: python

I am trying to validate input using Python for simple fields.

- map_x of type int
- map_y of type int
- obstacles of type bool

I have tried many of the suggestions here on SO. My code:

```
class Map(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # Note: These are defaults.
        # map_x and map_y both have a range of 20 <= x <= 100
        # obstacles = 'Y' || 'N'

        self.map_x = -1
        self.map_y = -1
        self.obstacles = '-'

    def forest_map(self):
        self.map_x = self.choice("Map Width")
        self.map_y = self.choice("Map Length")
        self.obstacles = self.choice("Obstacles (Y/N)")

    def choice(self, text):
        # Code
```

I have tried several different solutions at an attempt at staying true to the concept of "efficient" and "re-usable" code.

The reason for the text argument found in method 'choice':  I have made prompts that indicate what the user is interacting with (e.g.  choice = raw_input(text + "-> ")).

My solutions:

I have tried testing with if statements for the text argument, but that, to me, is too particular to this solution; thus, not re-usable.

I have tried using try / except, but, even still, it seems that my while statement is consuming input and is not returning a value to map_x and map_y.

I have tried (successfully! in a previous section for menu selection, not gathering user preferences) using a dictionary as follows:

```
# menu is an argument that takes a dictionary.
# dictionary can be found in a list of dictionaries named menu_list. 
# choice is a member of class Menus, and menu_list is defined in Menu's __init__.

def choice(self, menu):
    acceptable = menu
    if menu == self.menu_list[2]:
        choice = raw_input("Choice-> ")
        while choice not in acceptable:
            choice = raw_input("Choice-> ")

        Map().generate(choice)
```

I was only successful in testing for 'obstacles'. I used (while choice not in ['Y', 'y', 'N', 'n']: #Code

As of right now, I am only having issues with testing for integers WHILE keeping true to the aspect of re-usability and efficiency.

Is there a way I can see if the input (choice) contains letters of any kind and, thus, request for more input?
Is there a way I can, simultaneously, ensure that map_x / map_y are within the range 2 <= choice <= 100?

Thanks a bunch,
Akratix

=== EDIT 10/2/14 ===
I have come up with two implementations thanks to the solutions below.
In order to to validate input that is supposed to be an integer as well as within a set range, I use the following code snippet:

```
def map_choice(self, text):
    is_valid = False

    while not is_valid:
        try:
            value = int(raw_input(text + "-> "))
            if 2 > value or 100 < value:
                print "Invalid input!"
                continue
            return value

        except ValueError:
            print "Invalid input!"
```

In order to to validate input that is supposed to be a particular letter in a "list" of acceptable input, I use the following code snippet:

```
def obstacle_choice(self, text):
    is_valid = False

    while not is_valid:
        value = raw_input(text + "-> ")
        if any(value == x for x in ('Y', 'N', 'y', 'n')):
            return value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're off to a great start, but don't go overboard trying to generalize everything. You have two vastly different fields with different validation, so it makes sense to use two different "choice" functions.

It will be much simpler to use something like the following. You can even customize the fields error messages to tell the user why his input is invalid and be more helpful in general.

```
def forest_map(self):
    self.map_x = self.map_choice("Map Width")
    self.map_y = self.map_choice("Map Length")
    self.obstacles = self.obstacle_choice("Obstacles (Y/N)")

def map_choice(self, message)
    # here we use try except to make sure its an integer
    try:
        value = int(raw_input(message))
    except ValueError:
        print "Invalid input!"
        return -1
    # check range
    if 20 > value or 100 < value:
        print "Invalid input!"
        return -1
    return value

def obstacle_choice(self, message):
    value = raw_input(message)
    # check if its an acceptable answer
    if any( value == x for x in ('Y', 'N', 'y', 'n') ):
        return value
    print "Invalid input!"
    return -1
```

Alternately, if you have a lot of fields, it might be worthwhile to have one choice function that takes a validation function as an argument. Similar to your second `choice` function, but instead of taking a "menu" dict, we take a validation function.

```
def forest_map(self):
    valid_map = lambda x: 20 <= int(x) <= 100
    valid_obstacle = lambda x: any( x == y for y in ('Y', 'N', 'y', 'n') )

    # the choice function will guarantee its safe to use int on the result
    self.map_x = int(self.choice("Map Width", valid_map))
    self.map_y = int(self.choice("Map Length", valid_map))
    self.obstacles = self.choice("Obstacles (Y/N)", valid_obstacle)

def choice(self, message, validate):
    """
    Prompt a user for input and validate the input

    Args:
        message (str): Message to display at prompt
        validate (callable): callable of one parameter to validate input
    Returns:
        str: A valid user input
    """
    is_valid = False
    while not is_valid:
        # prompt for input
        value = raw_input(message)

        # validate input with our validation function
        # if validate(value) returns True, it ends the loop
        try:
            is_valid = validate(value)

        # maybe the validation function throws an exception
        # its best to catch the specific error class, but I'll use Exception for simplicity
        except Exception:
            is_valid = False
    return True
```

Finally, as to checking if an input contains any letters. You can use the `isalpha` method, which checks if every character in a string is a letter. To check if any char in a string is a letter you can use this.

```
value = raw_input('>')
contains_letters = any( c.isalpha() for c in value )
```

Comment: Kalhartt, thank you so much for the solutions you've provided. I have one question:

In the second solution, take the 'self.map_x =' line.
I'm confused because valid_map is not passed into 'choice', i.e.  the code is not int(self.choice("Map Width", valid_map)).

Why is the lambda function passed in as an argument of int()?
Am I misinterpreting the use of a lambda function?

Thanks a whole lot!

Comment: @Akratix you are absolutely right, it was a typo on my part and should have been `int(self.choice("Map Width", valid_map))`. Good catch, I'll edit and fix!

Answer (score 0):

Give the `choice` function an additional argument, which I usually call `type` (despite the collision with a builtin), that is a callable that will transform and validate the argument.

Use this example like `IntRange(2, 100)`

```
class IntRange(object):
    def __init__(self, min, max):
        self.min = min
        self.max = max
    def __call__(self, s):
        i = int(s) # throws
        if self.min <= i <= self.max:
            return i
        raise ValueError('%d is out of range' % i)
```

More types I've implemented are here: https://github.com/o11c/attoconf/blob/master/attoconf/types.py ; the `enum` type may be useful for y/n answers (but you might want something that does case normalization as well)